# How do you read a geojason url into a geopandas dataframe or pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, anaconda, geopandas

I tried this this but I got a messy outlook

```
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
Trial ='https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/t7ny-aygi.geojson?vendorid=VTS&payment_type=CRD&$limit=500'
trialck = requests.get(Trial).content
final = pd.read_csv(StringIO(trialck.decode('utf-8')), sep = '\t')
final.head()
```

{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":     [-73.87057,40.773757]},"properties":{"tpep_dropoff_datetime":"2013-04-         02T16:00:00.000","trip_distance":"11.279999999999999","dropoff_longitude":   "-73.870570000000001","pickup_latitude":"40.732897000000001","tolls_amount":"0","tip_amount":"0","payment_type":"CRD","fare_amount":"37","pickup_longitude":"-73.991167000000004","passenger_count":"6","store_and_fwd_flag":null,"extra":"0","vendorid":"VTS","pickup_location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.991167,40.732897]},"total_amount":"37.5","tpep_pickup_datetime":"2013-04-02T15:22:00.000","dropoff_latitude":"40.773757000000003","ratecodeid":"1","mta_tax":"0.5"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-74.00296,40.722112]},"properties":{"tpep_dropoff_datetime":"2013-07-19T07:52:00.000","trip_distance":"5.5","dropoff_longitude":"-74.002960000000002","pickup_latitude":"40.766105000000003","tolls_amount":"0","tip_amount":"3.8999999999999999","payment_type":"CRD","fare_amount":"19.5","pickup_longitude":"-73.954407000000003","passenger_count":"1","store_and_fwd_flag":null,"extra":"0","vendorid":"VTS","pickup_location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.954407,40.766105]},"total_amount":"23.899999999999999","tpep_pickup_datetime":"2013-07-19T07:33:00.000","dropoff_latitude":"40.722112000000003","ratecodeid":"1","mta_tax":"0.5"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `pandas.io.json.json_normalize`. In this case, it cannot handle the full json return, but if you specify the `'features'` key in the json, pandas can convert that to a dataframe.

```
import requests
url = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/t7ny-aygi.geojson?vendorid=VTS&payment_type=CRD&$limit=500'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['features'])
```